# Why do we only take into account the first product while calculating a limiting reactant?

Tags: stoichiometry

High school chemistry student here. Currently, we are learning stoichiometry and I noticed that when we calculate the limiting reactant of a reaction with multiple products, we almost always just take into account the first product. One sample of this can be found at chem.libretext

[image]

In this case, why are we only worried about the amount of CO2 that is produced? It would make sense to me sometimes choosing a product other than the first one, maybe H2O in this case, would affect the result we would get.

Am I thinking about this right?

Comment: It doesn't affect the result, you can choose whichever one you want. The amount of CO2 produced is directly proportional to the amount of H2O produced. (What's the proportionality factor? Well, the chemical equation tells you.)

Answer (score 2):

Well actually you don't need to calculate the moles or mass of any of the products. The stoichiometry of the reaction gives you the ratio of the two reactants.

For the reaction:
$$\ce{4C2H3Br3 + 11O2 -> 8CO2 + 6H2O + 6Br2}$$
we can divide all the coefficients by 4 so:
$$\ce{C2H3Br3 + 3.75O2 -> 2CO2 + 1.5H2O + 1.5Br2}$$

Now from the given answer there are 0.286 moles of  $\ce{C2H3Br3}$ and 1.53 moles of $\ce{O2}$

If:

- Moles($\ce{O2}$)/Moles($\ce{C2H3Br3}$) < 3.75 then $\ce{O2}$ is the limiting reagent
- Moles($\ce{O2}$)/Moles($\ce{C2H3Br3}$) = 3.75 then the reaction is perfectly balanced.
- Moles($\ce{O2}$)/Moles($\ce{C2H3Br3}$) > 3.75 then $\ce{C2H3Br3}$ is the limiting reagent

$\dfrac{1.53}{0.286} = 5.35$ so $\ce{C2H3Br3}$ is the limiting reagent.